# Probability of a name to be in the "Firstname Lastname" order

Tags: probability

I am trying to figure if a name is in the "Firstname Lastname" order, knowing the probability of each name to be either a firstname (class $A$) or a lastname (class $B$).

In other words, given two words $x$ and $y$, knowing $p(x\in A)$ and $p(y\in A)$, and having $p(x\in B) = 1-p(x\in A)$ and $p(y\in B) = 1-p(y\in A)$, I am trying to compute the probability of an ordered doublet $(x,y)$ to be of the type $(A,B)$ rather than $(B,A)$.

By construction, $p(x\in A \cap y\in A) = 0$ and $p(x\in B \cap y\in B) = 0$.

Should I just compare $p(x\in A)\cdot p(y\in B)$ with $p(x\in B)\cdot p(y\in A)$, simply ignoring $p(x\in A)\cdot p(y\in A)$ and $p(x\in B)\cdot p(y\in B)$ ?  If so, out of curiosity, how would it be justified ?  (I mean, the fact that we ignore those, resulting in a total probability being less than 1.)

NB : I have the very same issue for triplets $(x,y,z)$ being either $(A,A,B)$, $(A,B,B)$, $(B,A,A)$ or $(B,B,A)$.  If this approach is correct, I guess I can follow the same approach for other tuples ?  If not, I'm not sure if a general solution can be derived from this problem or if I should ask a separate question ?

Comment: I'm afraid you might get mixed up between the statistics of nouns belonging to given groups and the probability that the 2 given nouns belong to the groups in your example.

Why I say this is because if you call $f$ the frequency of words belonging to a certain group in general, then you don't have $f(x \in A \cap y \in A) = 0$. (because some firstnames are also lastnames and vice versa)

Comment: @Milloupe Indeed what I call $p(x\in A)$ is a statistics rather than a probability, sorry.  And I try to infer a probability from those statistics.  And yes, in principle $p(x\in A\cap y\in A)≠0$, but in my case $x$ and $y$ must be mutually exclusive, hence the "*by construction*".  Therefore I'm wondering if this leads to any subtility other than renormalizing $p(x\in A)\cdot p(y\in B) + p(x\in B)\cdot p(y\in A)$ ?

Comment: And actually, distinguishing between firstnames that can be lastnames and *vice versa* **is my very issue** : asserting the probability of "Gordon" to  be "Gordon Howard"'s first name…